# Erro estranho em C

Tags: c

Alguém sabe o porquê do valor do `i` mudar na condição `else if(i==721)`? Ele muda estranhamente, como podem ver no [vídeo do *debuging*](https://vimeo.com/312093656).

```
teamfile=fopen("team.txt", "r");
if(fgets(c, 3, teamfile)==NULL){
    printf("Please add one team at least before try to add players or managers.\n");
}
else{
    playerfile=fopen("player.txt", "r");
    for(i=1; i<=722; i++){
        if(fgets(c, 250, playerfile)==NULL && i<720){
            do{                     //NAME
                printf("Name: ");
                getchar();
                gets(c);
                w=0;
                for(j=0; j<49; j++){        //<49 supondo que, para o string máximo, o c[49]=\0
                    if(c[i]>32 && c[i]<65){
                        w=1;
                        printf("Invalid characters. Try again. \n"); break;
                    }
                }                                                   
            }while(w==1);
            strcpy(player[i].name, c);

            do{                 //BIRTH DATE
                w=0;
                printf("Player birth date (dd mm yyyy): ");
                scanf("%i %i %i", &d, &m, &y); 
                w=dateverific(d, m,y);
            }while(w==1);
            player[i].birth.day=d;
            player[i].birth.month=m;
            player[i].birth.year=y;

            nations(i);     //NATION
            positions(i);       //POSITION
            teamlists(i, a);        //TEAM
            fclose(playerfile); 
            playerfile=fopen("player.txt", "a");
            fprintf(playerfile, "%s %d %33s %d %d %d %s %s\n", player[i].position, i, player[i].team, player[i].birth.day, player[i].birth.month, player[i].birth.year, player[i].nation, player[i].name); // explicar troca de id pela position realacianado com o fscafn do string clube name
            fclose(playerfile);
            break;
        }
        else if(i==721){
            printf("Impossible to add more players, all team are full.");
        }
        else{
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Como foi declarada sua variável `i`?

Comment: Normalmente, int i=1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como se pode ver no vídeo mesmo, o valor de i é sobreescrito com lixo antes da linha com o  `if` que você põe na pergunta - e sim na própria linha que contém `if(fgets(c, 250, playerfile)==NULL && i<720)`.
Como a comparação `i < 720` não altera o valor de i, o que "sobra" é que o que está colocando lixo em `i` é a chamada a `fgets`. essa é uma função segura, mas tem que ser usada da forma correta.  Em particular, o parâmetro de buffer para onde vão ser lidos os seus dados, tem que conter memória livre  - ou seja, seu `c` tem ou ter sido declarado com `char c[250];`, ou ter sido declarado como um ponteiro *e* apontado para uma região de memória alocada - algo como `char *c; ...; c = malloc(250); if (c==NULL) {exit(1); /* falha ao alocar memoria */}`

O erro provavelmente acontece por que você está supondo que fgets aloca a memoria sozinho - o que não acontece - no meu sistema aqui (que é posix-conformant), a descrição da função é:

> fgets(s)  reads  in  at  most one less than size characters from stream
>   and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.

Ou seja - o espaço apontado pelo ponteiro que vai no primeiro parâmetro da chamada *já tem* que estar reservado.

Bom - essa é a resposta - eu deixo duas dicas adicionais:

(1) ao fazer perguntas **sempre** inclua uma versão do seu programa completa, que possa replicar o erro. Nesse caso, por exemplo, o problema está na declaração da variável `c` e em sua não inicialização - mas vendo só o trecho de código que você colocou, não tem como saber disso. Só deu pra entender o que acontece por conta do vídeo do debug, mas isso é que não é pra ser necessário - só ver as demais perguntas do site. Quando eu digo "versão" - quer dizer que você não precisa - e em geral não deve - colocar seu programa original completo, mas sim, pegar o seu programa, e apagar tudo o que não for relacionado com o problema, mas manter um trecho compilável e que apresente o mesmo problema que motivou a pergunta.

(2) òtimo - você aprendeu a programar em C, e manipular arquivos,  e está tentando criar um programa real pra uso "de verdade". Só que C é uma das últimas linguagens que você deveria utilizar pra isso. Por ser uma linguagem de relativamente baixo nível de programação, você tem que se preocupar com detalhes como - alocar memória para *cada* uso de string que for fazer, usar funções desenhadas na década de 70 para manipular strings, que requerem verifição de código de erro em cada chamada, funções que são perigosas devido a não checagem de comprimento de dados - (legal, você está usando `fgets` em vez de `fget` - mas está usando `scanf` simples, que com uma digitação maliciosa pode dar segfault no seu programa, por exemplo).

Para aplicações desse tipo - que envolvem entrada e saída de texto, manipulação de arquivos de texto, sua aplicação vai ser umas 30 vezes mais simples (sem exagero, e umas 3 vezes menos código, pelo menos), se você a fizer numa linguagem dinâmica de alto nível - linguagens como Python, Javascript, Ruby ou PHP - por exemplo. Em todas essas, a alocação de strings como objetos internos é automática, arquivos de texto são lidos linha a linha, sem preocupação com a memória, e existem funções muito práticas embutidas para manipluar strings e verificar seu conteúdo.

Eu sugiro a linguagem Python, embora isso possa ser um pouco ao gosto do freguês - mas sério: se você acompanhar por 3 horas qualquer tutorial (em formato texto) de Python, deve ser o suficiente para você re-escrever a sua aplicação como ela está nessa linguagem e continuar o desenvolvimento a partir dali. Se conseguir ler em Inglês, recomendo mesmo o [tutorial oficial da linguagem](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). Caso contrário, no google aparecem várias opções em português.

Por favor, entenda que isso não uma "birra" contra C - a linguagem continua sendo, possivelmente, a mais importante de todo o universo de computação - e tem nichos em que é vital, por exemplo, IoT - mas não é a melhor ferramenta para o tipo de programa que você está tentando fazer aí, nem é gentil com programadores mesmo em nível intermediário.

Comment: Muito obrigado, está resolvido!

Comment: Se resolveu seu problema, você pode marcar a resposta como "aceita".